# The question of whether a function of two variables is differentiable at one point.

Tags: calculus

if $\lim _{\left(x,y\right)\to \left(0,0\right)}\frac{f\left(x,y\right)-f\left(0,0\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$,is $f(x,y)$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

why?

I got a sulotion that:

> $\lim _{\left(x,y\right)\to \left(0,0\right)}\frac{f\left(x,y\right)-f\left(0,0\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$

> => $f_{x}\left(x,0\right)^{'}=\lim \:_{x\to \:0}\frac{f\left(x,0\right)-f\left(0,0\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+0^2}}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{x}=0\:$

> In the same way, => $f_y\left(0,y\right)^{'}=0$

> ...other process.

**I'm confused:**

> $\lim _{\left(x,y\right)\to \left(0,0\right)}\frac{f\left(x,y\right)-f\left(0,0\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\:\lim \:_{x\to \:0}\frac{f\left(x,0\right)-f\left(0,0\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+0^2}}$

Is right?

Comment: Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The general definition of the derivative for a function $f:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ is the unique linear map $A:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ such that
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\|f(x + h)-f(x)-A(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0
$$
where $h \in \mathbb R^m$. Note that the norm in numerator and the denomenator are those of $\mathbb R^m$ and $\mathbb R^m$ respectively.

In the case we have, $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^m$, (possibly $m=1$) and $x = (0,0)$, it follows
$$
\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{\|h\|}  = \frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$
where $h \in \mathbb R^2$. That means
$$
\lim _{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0 
\implies \lim _{h\to 0}\frac{\|f(0+h)-f(0)\|}{\|h\|}=0 
$$
The answer is YES!, with $A = 0$

Comment: sorry,I can't understand.

Comment: @ikigai I hope it is now clear

Comment: Sorry,I still don't understand it. Maybe I'm a little deep for me.Thank you anyway!@Physor